# for each loop using a datagridview

Tags: vb.net, loops, datagridview

I trying to perform a calculation on some values within a DGV that has been imported from data within an xls file. but I cant get the loop to work. what I need it to do is read the value of the cells in column 2 and column 3 of each row, put them in to a text box and then output the result of the calculation to column 4 of the DVG. I would post the code but frankly I haven't got anything real to go on. am I correct in thinking I need to be using a For each loop???

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you load the DataGridView? Do you have some kind of DataTable that could be modified to add calculated columns? Perhaps the answer is in your code that loads the grid. Please show it

Comment: Have you got this working yet?

Comment: Not as yet.... other projects have taken priority but this is very much outstanding........
I'll post a better description later today of the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I find it Little hard understanding your request... But how about this?

```
For Each Row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        Dim CellValues As New List(Of String)
        Dim Failed As Boolean = False
        For x = 1 To 2 'This is right. It's NOT supposed to be 2 To 3.
            If Row.Cells(x).Value <> Nothing Then
                CellValues.Add(Row.Cells(x).Value.ToString())
            ElseIf Row.Cells(x).Value = Nothing Then
                Failed = True
            End If
        Next

        If Failed = True Then
            Continue For
        End If

        TextBox1.AppendText(CellValues(0) & " + " & CellValues(1) & Environment.NewLine)

        Row.Cells(3).Value = CInt(CellValues(0)) + CInt(CellValues(1))
Next
```

[image: DataGridView Test]